# Web Requests behaving differently when app is installed from the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, asihttprequest

This is a real doosra, so my hope is just that someone has come across this before and found a solution.

I have an app that posts requests to a server to check for updates to its data (it's been around for a while, so we're using `ASIHTTPRequest`). When doing this, the app also sends the current data library as a JSON array in a URL parameter. During development, everything works great, and even so when using Ad-Hoc distribution and Enterprise distribution. The problem arises when the app is distributed using the App Store, all of a sudden the requests are not posting the required URL parameter, which causes a server side failure.

My question is, does anyone know why an app would suddenly decide to behave differently when uploaded to the App Store? It seems odd that exactly the same code would work perfectly in Enterprise distribution and Ad-Hoc distribution, but then not work on the App Store.

Further information: The offline data is stored in CoreData, an `ASIFormDataRequest` is used for the request and the JSON is encoded using `JSONKit`.

Comment: Seems very weird. Can you point out the exact differences in the request URL?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does "it's been around for a while, so we're using ASIHTTPRequest" mean? Is ASIHTTPRequest not the first choice these days?

Comment: @stavash It's simply the lack of the parameter as far as I'm aware, I don't run the server side of things but this is what I'm told.

Comment: @TimBüthe `ASIHTTPRequest` has been deprecated by the developer.

Comment: Still, I have been working with it for months since iOS 5.0 was out (just a matter of switching the linked library dependancies) and it hasn't given me any grief...

Comment: @stavash I still have it running on a few projects, so I don't blame the library. The only difference between the builds though is the certificate they're being signed with, and that shouldn't have any effect on the behaviour. I'm completely stumped, and that doesn't happen often!

Comment: Can you grab an appstore request and a working request using a tool like wireshark or tcpdump on the server?

Comment: Are you testing clean installs?  e.g. after deleting the app?  How about after combinations of Airplane mode switching off or on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was to do with an apns device token being delivered with the update request on the App Store.